# why is my wrapper not rendering my component at all using jest?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am trying to create a react jest test for one of my components I have created a mock component for the test just to make it easier to see what the test is actually testing.

For some reason my wrapper seems to be empty I have no idea why

test file:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { shallow, render } from "enzyme";
import MapComp from "../components/MapComp";
import { MapContainer, Polyline } from "react-leaflet";

describe("MapComp", () => {
  it("renders a Polyline component with the correct props", () => {
    const mockData = {
      positions: [
        [55.79104, -3.96177],
        [55.79093, -3.9621],
        // ... add more coordinates here
      ],
      name: "Cold morning run",
      activityType: "Run",
      duration: "6.43",
      date: "2022-11-30T07:46:36Z",
      distance: 1623,
      // ... add more properties here
    };

    const MockComponent = () => {
      const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }, 1000);
      return !isLoading ? (
        <div>
          <MapContainer
            center={getInitPosition()}
            zoom={15}
            scrollWheelZoom={false}
            style={props.style}
          >
            <TileLayer
              attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
              url={
                props.mapStyle
                  ? props.mapStyle
                  : "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
              }
            />

            {!Array.isArray(props.activityData) &&
              !props.activityData.polylines && (
                <Polyline
                  positions={props.activityData.positions}
                  pathOptions={{
                    color: mapColors[props.activityData.activityType],
                  }}
                >
                  <Marker
                    position={[
                      props.activityData.positions[0][0],
                      props.activityData.positions[0][1],
                    ]}
                  >
                    <Popup>{props.activityData.name}</Popup>
                  </Marker>
                </Polyline>
              )}

            {Array.isArray(props.activityData.polylines) &&
              props.activityData.polylines.length > 1 &&
              props.activityData.polylines.map((activity, idx) => (
                <Polyline
                  key={idx}
                  positions={activity.positions}
                  pathOptions={{ color: mapColors[activity.activityType] }}
                >
                  {props.showMarkers ? (
                    <Marker
                      position={[
                        activity.positions[0][0],
                        activity.positions[0][1],
                      ]}
                    >
                      <Popup>
                        <div>
                          <h2>{"Name: " + activity.name}</h2>
                        </div>
                      </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                  ) : (
                    <div></div>
                  )}
                </Polyline>
              ))}
          </MapContainer>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <p>Loading...</p>
        </div>
      );
    };

    const wrapper = shallow(<MockComponent />);

    const polylineData = wrapper.find("Polyline");

    expect(polylineData).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(polylineData.prop("positions")).toEqual(mockData.positions);
    expect(polylineData.prop("pathOptions")).toEqual({ color: "blue" });
  });
});
```

these are the issues I am getting back from my test on why it is failing:

[image]

I cannot figure out the issue with the test for the life of me can anyway spot my issue I am also pretty new to jest.

Answer (score 0):

If your component uses a `setTimeout` to delay rendering, you'll probably want to use [Jest Timer Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks) to advance all timers and execute the `setTimeout` callback. I haven't tested this, but something like this should work:

```js
jest.useFakeTimers();

describe("MapComp", () => {
  it("renders a Polyline component with the correct props", () => {
    ...

    const wrapper = shallow(<MockComponent />);
    
    // Fast-forward until all timers have been executed
    jest.runAllTimers();

    const polylineData = wrapper.find("Polyline");
    expect(polylineData).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```